# pushforward in non-multiplicative generalized cohomology theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Let's fix a $(B,f)$ structure with Thom spectra $MB$. I'd like to know the condition for a not-necessarily-multiplicative generalized cohomology theory $E^*$ such that for a fibration $X\to Y$ with $(B,f)$ structure with $n$-dimensional fiber to have the pushforward map $E^*(X)\to E^{*-n}(Y)$.

When $E$ is multiplicative, the condition is that there is a homomorphism $MB\to E$. When $E$ is not multiplicative, is the condition that $E$ is a module of $MB$ enough?  I think it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and is explained in detail in any textbook. See e.g. Rudyak "On Thom Spectra, Orientability, and Cobordism", Chapter 5, Section 2.